# How to hide all highlights of a certain color in a Word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word, hide

In my Word document (.docx) there are multiple highlight colors.

I found this code that deletes all yellow highlights after have found them. I only need them to be hidden:

```vb
Sub Highlight()
Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveDocument.Range

With r.Find
    .Highlight = True
    Do While .Execute(FindText:="", Forward:=True) = True
        If r.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow Then
            r.HighlightColorIndex = wdAuto
            r.Collapse 0
        End If
    Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't change the highlight.  Set the Hidden property of the text to be true. e.g. r.Font.Hidden = True.  You will need to set your display properties correctly to show the effect of text being hidden (file options display 'Always show these formatting marks on the screen' ensure Hidden is unchecked and show all formatting marks is unchecked.  If the hidden text is a whole  word(s) then you wil end up with a double space that marks whare the highlighted text is (unless of course you also highlighted the spaces )

Comment: Many thanks freeflow for your help, that works!

Answer (score 0):

The code you found lacks some important checks. Try the following:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Highlight = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    If .HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow Then .Font.Hidden = True
    'The next If ... End If block is needed in case the highlighted content is in a table and includes the end-of-cell marker or end-of-row marker
    If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
      If .End = .Cells(1).Range.End - 1 Then
        .End = .Cells(1).Range.End
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        If .Information(wdAtEndOfRowMarker) = True Then
          .End = .End + 1
        End If
      End If
    End If
    'The next line is needed in case the highlighted content includes the final paragraph break
    If .End = ActiveDocument.Range.End Then Exit Do
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Huge thanks macropod! I tried it, it works very well!

Another question if I may... for example, in some paragraphs highlighted in Turquoise, few words are highlighted in DarkYellow, do you know how can I hide these words too? Do I need a new code for that?

Comment: You could simply add more lines like If .HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow Then .Font.Hidden = True, specifying the required highlight colour in each case.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, it saved me valuable time!